# Can anyone tell me what "on O+ for instant apps" mean?

Tags: android, android-version

The following information is from [Android Developer's page](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/splitinstall/SplitInstallHelper#updateappinfo). 
I like to understand What "O+" in the context below. Is it version like Oreo?

> ## updateAppInfo
>
> `void updateAppInfo (Context context)`
>
> Updates application info based on currently installed splits.
>
> Note #1: This method must be called after split is installed on O+ for instant apps, so that application components can see new resources and code from new splits.
>
> Note #2: This method will update application info reference in application thread object.
>
> Note #3: This method should only be called on O+.
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
>  // SplitInstallAPI callbacks
>   public void onStateUpdate(SplitInstallSessionState splitInstallSessionState) {
>     if (splitInstallSessionState.status() == SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED) {
>       // Use SplitInstallHelper API on O+ to update application info after the splits are
>       // installed.
>       if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastO()) {
>         // Updates app info with new split information making split artifacts available to the
>         // app on subsequent requests.
>         SplitInstallHelper.updateAppInfo(context);
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ```

Comment: *`Is it version like Oreo?`* YES

Comment: This might help too: [Android Versions & History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In this case O is short for Oreo. Each major version of Android (from 1.2 onwards) is named after a dessert or other sweet food, and versions are [codenamed in alphabetical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) starting with [C for Cupcake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_1.5_Cupcake_(API_3)). Versions are often shortened down to their first letter for quick reference, or when the version name has not yet been decided (which is currently the case for [Android P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_P)).

So in your example, the function `BuildCompat.isAtLeastO()` checks that the current device is running at least Android Oreo (API level 26).

Answer (score 0):

[Instant apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/) is a mini-application that does not need to be installed. Not all standard methods can work in it.

Comment: OP is asking for what `O` stands for in this context, not what Instant Apps does.